# What's the recommended number of values I can pass via bundle between fragments before refactoring to use shared viewModels?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say there are 2 difference scenarios:

1. I have one value to pass between fragments (assume a ID)
2. I have 10 values (assume a `Person` class that doesn't implement Parcelable)

I'm aware of 2 ways of passing data between Fragments (leaving out the Navigation Component library):

1. Using a `Bundle` and passing the data to the target fragment
2. Using a shared Android `ViewModel` between fragments and observe the live data

It's definitely easy to use the approach #1 but you need to handle null/empty values and the tags used

Approach #2 seems to be more safe and logically seems to follow Android Arch approach, at the cost of extra code.

My question is, when to use either approach? Any Google defined recommendations?

**Update:**

For the sake of the argument, let's say `Fragment1` contains a RecyclerView backed by a `Fragment1ViewModel`. `Fragment2` is a bottom sheet fragment (extended from `BottomSheetDialogFragment`). When user clicks on an item in the recycler view from Fragment 1 we open the bottom sheet (Fragment2). Now, to pass the data between Fragments, is it suggested to convert `Fragment1ViewModel` into shared viewmodel?

Comment: Is your view model and fragments the same, or just would a shared view model just be a "convenient" place to put this "stuff"?  Why not a repository that's scope lasts as long as needed - each view model can just depend upon the same repository instance? That way all view models are a true representation of their associated views without breaking encapsulation. Sharing view models for different views seems to break encapsulation - all fragments can access all functions of the view model, whether applicable of not.

Comment: Updated my question with an example